# How can i merge two schemas

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I want to combine two schemas in realm db and perform operations on them, just like join in sql. But i don't know how to do it. I did not

List item

understand anything from the document. How can I do that?I have two schematics

```
const barkod = {
  name: 'barkod',
  properties: {
    StokNo: { type: 'int', indexed: true },
    Barkod: { type: 'string', indexed: true },
    Birim: 'string',
    BarkodTipi: 'string',
    Aciklama: 'string?',
    YStokNo: 'int'
  }
  // primaryKey: 'Barkod',
}

const stok = {
  name: 'stok',
  primaryKey: 'StokNo',
  properties: {
    StokNo: 'int',
    StokAdi: { type: 'string', indexed: true },
    StokKisaAdi: 'string',
    StokKodu: 'string',
    StokTanimi: 'string',
    GrupKodu: 'string',
    KdvOranP: { type: 'int', default: 0 },
    KDVOranT: { type: 'int', default: 0 },
    OzelKodu1: 'string',
    OzelKodu2: 'string',
    OzelKodu3: 'string'
  }
}`enter code here`
 and I want to join these two schemas
 
         
'SELECT Stok.StokAdi, Barkod, StokNo FROM ? AS Barkod JOIN ? AS Stok ON Barkod.StokNo = Stok.StokNo',
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's important for questions to be clear and contain the code you're having difficulty with. A join does not combine schemas - A JOIN is a means for combining fields from two or more tables by using values common to each. For us to help we would need to see your Realm models and understand the relationship between them as well as what you're attempting to do. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. And this is how I did it. Hope it helps for those who have this problem.

```
 const CarSchema = {
    name: 'Car',
    properties: {
      make: 'string',
      model: 'string',
      miles: {type: 'int', default: 0},
    },
  };
  const PersonSchema = {
    name: 'Person',
    properties: {
      name: 'string',
      birthday: 'date',
      cars: 'Car[]',
      //   picture:  'data?' // optional property
    },
  };

  const exp1 = () => {
    var person;
    Realm.open({schema: [CarSchema, PersonSchema]})
      .then(realm => {
        realm.write(() => {
          person = realm.create('Person', {
            name: 'ayşegül',
            birthday: new Date(1995, 11, 25),
            //  cars: 'Car[]',
          });
          console.log(person.cars);
          let carList = person.cars;
          carList.push({make: 'Honda', model: 'model1', miles: 100});
          carList.push({make: 'Toyota', model: 'model2', miles: 200});
          console.log(person);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```